# How to use the Google-Cloud-Messaging API in Qt

Tags: android, c++, qt, google-cloud-messaging

I want to implement the Google-Cloud-Messaging API into my project and now I have come to the point where i need to implement the code in my application. ( I have already referenced the library using the CMD tools provided and created the AndroidManifest.xml )

But I am having a hard time figuring out how to use the API at all.

In the docs (http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/client.html)  i see them implementing all these functions but i dont know how to call them from my code as I am using Qt and not JAVA.

Do i need to include some header files or something like that?

**My question is: How do I import these API libraries in my Qt code?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need to use the [Android Extras](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtandroidextras-index.html) and build the gcm code in Java. This is done by creating a class that extends the QtActivity class in Android. A good example how to do that can be found [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtandroidextras-notification-example.html), at least it shows how to make the call from Qt to native Android.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. See [How do I write a good answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).